# Dropdown options stays on top, in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

```
<div id="growDiv"></div>
<select id="combobox">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>0</option>
</select>

<script>
  $('#growDiv').on('mouseover', function (){
    $(this).css('height', '200px');
  }).on('mouseout', function (){
    $(this).css('height', '75px');
  })
</script>

<style>
    #growDiv {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gold;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    #combobox {
      margin-top: 75px;
    }
</style>
```

You can see it in: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dHN2K/

In Safari, if I unfold the dropdown options and then I 'hover' the yellow div, the options stays on top...... how can I fix this?.

I tried also $('select').remove(); but it remains there!!

Thank you!

Comment: Don't see any difference in ff, chrome and safari.

Comment: Update your safari version. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: In Chrome I solved it wrapping the select in a parent div and hidding that div in the mouseover event. But in Safari it's impossible!

Comment: Lower `z-index` on the select list itself would possibly help. Like @SudipPal I'm not experiencing this issue, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the select on mouse over.
http://jsfiddle.net/dHN2K/2/

See the changes that i've made.

```
  $('#growDiv').on('mouseover', function (){
    $(this).css('height', '200px');
      $("#combobox").hide();
  }).on('mouseout', function (){
    $(this).css('height', '75px');
       $("#combobox").show();
  })
```

Comment: I must specify that it's Safari for Windows. With this approach the combo is hidden but if I expand the combo and then without selecting any option I hover the yellow div, the combo options remains there.

Answer (score 0):

this works in safari 5.1.7

```
#growDiv:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

it won't work in old ie's but then you can just use the javascript method

Comment: I must specify that it's Safari for Windows (5.1.7). With this approach the combo is hidden but if I expand the combo and then (without selecting any option) I hover the yellow div, the combo options remains there.

Comment: Sorry, the comment was for red_alert answer

Comment: this is easily the best solution as you don't need any js for Safari support at least

Answer (score 0):

This was bothering me for some sad reason! heres the long, definitive answer:

```
#growDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gold;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

#combobox {
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
}

#growDiv:hover {
    height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49b6e/